# Logging in to Wordpress through CodeIgniter DX Authentication

Tags: php, authentication, wordpress, codeigniter

I'm about to start a very large project of rebuilding my companies intranet.  The plan is to have most of the intranet live in a CI application.  I chose to use CI because i'm very familiar with all the CI methods.  Some sections of the intranet are going to be wordpress blogs.  For example the Human Resources Dept. and the Marketing Dept will have their own wordpress blogs.

Ideally my plan is to log on to the intranet, with a CI authentication library like DXAuth by querying the Active Directory of the company.  When I return the AD information for the user I will by saving their group memberships into a session.

It would be fantastic if I could have that session information of the user be used by wordpress to log the user as an editor if they are a member of the Marketing Group.  And allow users who are not members of the group be able to comment on that blog, with out logging into wordpress.

My question is if there are any CI classes or Wordpress Plugins, or tutorals out there, of this sort of integration with the two systems.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert at all, but maybe you could store their wordpress username, and password in the database, and then use that through CI to access wp-login.php through a controller by sending that info through a view/form. and in your CI app on their profile they can enter that information...?